# Pip install h3 fails due to "make no targets specified and no makefile found"

Tags: python, visual-c++, makefile, cmake

I´ve tried to install the h3 bindings for python today on my Windows machine but ran into some problems while installing. After starting `pip install h3` I receive the following error message:

```
    HEAD is now at cdd6819 Merge pull request #111 from isaacbrodsky/version-3.1.0
  + cmake -DENABLE_FORMAT=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26726.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Checking for stack allocation function (alloca) - Success
  -- Checking for VLA support - Failed
  CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:218 (message):
    clang-format was not detected, so automatic source code reformatting is
    disabled


  CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:230 (message):
    clang-tidy was not detected, so source code linting is disabled


  -- Found Doxygen: C:/Program Files/doxygen/bin/doxygen.exe (found version "1.8.14") found components:  doxygen dot
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/speic/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-781fg09z/h3/h3c
  + make
  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\speic\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-781fg09z\h3\setup.py", line 60, in <module>
      distclass=BinaryDistribution)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\speic\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-781fg09z\h3\setup.py", line 23, in run
      install_h3(h3_version)
    File "C:\Users\speic\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-781fg09z\h3\setup.py", line 16, in install_h3
      'bash ./.install.sh {}'.format(h3_version), shell=True, check=True)
    File "c:\users\speic\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'bash ./.install.sh v3.1.0' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Cmake, make and c compiler are all installed and added to the path. It seems like make can not find any make file but as far as I can see it the build files were generated succesfully.

I hope anyone can help me with the installation as I´m still quite new to the building process and these error messages seem quite cryptic to me.

Thank you :)

Edit:
I feel like I´ve managed to solve some of the problems but somehow I´m still lost on how to go on.
My steps so far:

1. I´ve cloned the [h3-py Repository from github](https://github.com/uber/h3-py)
2. I´ve modified the [.install.sh file](https://github.com/uber/h3-py/blob/master/.install.sh) in the following way:
   I´ve changed `cmake -DENABLE_FORMAT=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .` to `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" -DENABLE_FORMAT=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .`
   After this the build process seems to work just fine. However I get the an error after the build process: `+ ls -l 'lib/libh3*'
   ls: cannot access 'lib/libh3*': No such file or directory` 
   And the error message is correct. There isn´t any directory lib but there´s a `libh3.dll` file in the `bin/directory` So I´ve tried to swap `lib` with `bin` in the `.install.sh` file

```
ls -l bin/libh3*
cp bin/libh3* ../h3/out
if [ -e ../build ] && [ -d ../build ]; then
    LIBNAME=`ls ../build/ | grep '^lib'`
    mkdir -p ../build/$LIBNAME/h3/out
    cp bin/libh3* ../build/$LIBNAME/h3/out
fi
popd
rm -rf h3c
```

instead of

```
ls -l lib/libh3*
cp lib/libh3* ../h3/out
if [ -e ../build ] && [ -d ../build ]; then
    LIBNAME=`ls ../build/ | grep '^lib'`
    mkdir -p ../build/$LIBNAME/h3/out
    cp lib/libh3* ../build/$LIBNAME/h3/out
fi
popd
rm -rf h3c
```

And the shell script executes just fine. However I don´t know if everything I´ve done is correct and how I am supposed to go on from there, as apparently no h3 package is installed at this point.

Comment: "Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017" - CMake generates solution for Visual Studio, not a Makefile. It seems that your CMake is configured with `Visual Studio 15 2017` as a default generator. According to [this mailing](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16339), there is no way to change default generator for CMake (except than deleting Visual Studio from the PC). I don't know whether `pip` is able to run CMake with proper `-G` option.

Comment: You using Windows, so CMake will generate Visual Studio solution by default. Not make. So my guess is - current python h3 bindings can't be built using pip. See https://github.com/uber/h3-py/blob/master/.install.sh for details. Perhaps if you'll change 'make' to 'cmake --build .' it will work somehow.